# jQuery AJAX Update and Show/Hide Div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Need some help doing my update Ajax call. What I want my code to do is to show when on click my update form and pass the data from the form to my update via AJAX. So far the form isn't showing on click nor is the update working. Everything else seems to be working right except for that.

index.php

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php' ?>
<div class="main" id="maincontent">
<div class="main-section">
    <div class="add-section">
        <form action="app/add.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <?php if(isset($_GET['mess']) && $_GET['mess'] == 'error'){ ?>
            <label for="title">To Do*</label>
            <input type="text" id= "title" name="title" 
            style="border-color: #ff6666"
            placeholder="This is required" aria-label="You need to create a to do!"/> 

            <label for="month">Month</label>
            <input type="text" id="month" name="month" placeholder="Month Not Required" aria-label="Enter a month if needed"/>
            
            <label for="year">Year</label>
            <input type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="Year Not Required" aria-label="Enter a year if needed"/>

            <button type="submit" aria-label="Enter"> &plus; </button>

            <?php }else{ ?>
            <label for="title">To Do*</label>
                <input type="text" id= "title" name="title" placeholder="Enter a To Do" aria-label="Enter a To Do"/>
            
            <label for="month">Month</label>    
                <input type="text" id="month" name="month" placeholder="Enter Month [1-12]" aria-label="Enter month if needed for your to do"/>  
            
            <label for="year">Year</label>     
                <input type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="Enter Year [yyyy]" aria-label="Enter a year if needed for your to do"/>

            <button type="submit" aria-label="Enter"> &plus; </button>
                
            <?php } ?>
        </form>

    </div>  
    <?php
        $todos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM todos  ORDER BY id DESC"); 
    ?>
    <div class="show-todo-section">
    <?php if($todos->rowCount() <= 0){?>
        <div class="todo-item">
            <div class="empty">
                <p>Enter a To Do!</p>
                <img src="img/f.jpg" alt="Notebook" width="100%" height="175px" />
                
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>  

    <?php while($todo = $todos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <div class="todo-item">
            <span id="<?php echo $todo['id']; ?>" class="remove-to-do" aria-label="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:18px"></i></span>
      

            <span id="<?php echo $todo['id']; ?>" class="update-to-do" aria-label="Edit">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:18px"></i></span>

            <?php if($todo['checked']) { ?> 
                <input type="checkbox" data-todo-id="<?php echo $todo['id']; ?>" class="check-box" checked />

                <h2 class="checked"><?php echo $todo['title'] ?></h2>

            <?php }else{ ?>
                <input type="checkbox" data-todo-id="<?php echo $todo['id']; ?>" class="check-box">
                <h2><?php echo $todo['title'] ?></h2>

            <?php } ?>
            <br>
            <small>Created: <?php echo $todo['date_time'] ?> &nbsp; </small> 
            <div style="display:none;" class="update"><?php include 'updateForm.php'?></div> 
            <!---->
        </div>
           
        
    <?php } ?>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove-to-do').click(function(){
        const id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post("app/remove.php",
        {
            id: id
        },
        (data) =>{
            if(data){
                $(this).parent().hide(600);
            }
        }         
        );  
    });       
    $(".check-box").click(function(e){
    const id = $(this).attr('data-todo-id');  
    
    $.post("app/check.php",
        {
            id: id
        },
        (data) =>{
            if(data != 'error')
            {
                const h2 = $(this).next();
                if(data === '1'){
                    h2.removeClass('checked');
                }else{
                    h2.addClass('checked');
                }
            }
        }
        );
    }); /* */
    $(".update-to-do").click(function(e){
        const id = $(this).attr('id');
        var title = $(this).attr('id'); //find
        var month = $(this).attr('id');
        var year = $(this).attr('id');
    
    $.post("app/update.php",
        {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            month: month,
            year : year
            
        },
        (data) =>{
            //alert(id);
            
            if(data != 'error')
            {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".update");

                if(form.hide()){
                    form.show();
                }else{
                    form.hide();
                }
            }
        }
        );
    });
             
});
```

updateForm.php

```
  <div class="add-section"> 
      <form action="app/update.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <?php if(isset($_GET['mess']) && $_GET['mess'] == 'error'){ ?>
                <label for="id" style="display:none;"></label>
                <input type="hidden" id= "id" name="id" value="<?php echo  $_GET['id']; ?>" aria-label=""/>

                <label for="title">To Do*</label>
                <input type="text" id= "title" name="title" 
                style="border-color: #ff6666"
                placeholder="This is required" aria-label="You need to create a to do!"/> 

                <label for="month">Month</label>
                <input type="text" id="month" name="month" placeholder="Month Not Required" aria-label="Enter a month if needed"/>
                
                <label for="year">Year</label>
                <input type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="Year Not Required" aria-label="Enter a year if needed"/>

                <button type="submit" aria-label="Enter"> &plus; </button>

                <?php }else{ ?>
                <label for="id" style="display:none;"></label>
                    <!--<input type="hidden" id= "id" name="id" value="<?php //echo  $_GET['id']; ?>" aria-label="id"/> -->
                
                <label for="title">To Do*</label>
                    <input type="text" id= "title" name="title" placeholder="Enter a To Do" aria-label="Enter a To Do"/>
                
                <label for="month">Month</label>    
                    <input type="text" id="month" name="month" placeholder="Enter Month [1-12]" aria-label="Enter month if needed for your to do"/>  
                
                <label for="year">Year</label>     
                    <input type="text" id="year" name="year" placeholder="Enter Year [yyyy]" aria-label="Enter a year if needed for your to do"/>
                    <div class="pad"></div>
                <button type="submit" aria-label="Enter"> &plus; </button>
                    
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
   </div>
```

update.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    require '../includes/conn.php';
    include 'func.php';

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo $id;
    $title = $_POST['titleUp'];
    $month = $_POST['monthUp'];
    $year = $_POST['yearUp'];
    $dateMonth;
    $futureDate;
    
    if(empty($id))
    {
        header("Location: ../updateForm.php?id=" . $id . "mess=error");
    }
    else
    {
        if( (!empty($title)) &&  (empty($month)) && (empty($year)) )
        { //need to filter 0 so its registered as not empty
            $title = validTitle($title);
    
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE todos(title) VALUE(?) WHERE id=?");
            $res = $stmt->execute([$title, $id]); 
    
            if($res)
            {
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }
            else
            {           
                header("Location: ../updateForm.php?id=" . $id .  "mess=error");
            }
            $conn= null;
            exit();
    
        }
        else if( (!empty($title)) && (!empty($month)) && (empty($year)) )
        {
            $title = validTitle($title);
            $month = validMonth($month);
            $dateMonth = dateMonth($month);
            $year = date("Y");
    
            $futureDate = futureDate($dateMonth, $year);
            
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE todos (title, future_datetime) VALUES (?,?) WHERE id=?");
            $res = $stmt->execute([$title ,$futureDate, $id]); 
    
            if($res)
            {
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }
            else
            {           
            header("updateForm.php?id=" . $id .  "mess=error");
            }
            $conn= null;
            exit();
        }  
        else if( (!empty($title)) && (!empty($month)) && (!(empty($year))))
        {
            $title = validTitle($title);
            $month = validMonth($month);
            $dateMonth = dateMonth($month);
            $year = validYear($year);
    
            $futureDate = futureDate($dateMonth, $year);
            
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE todos (title, future_datetime) VALUES (?,?) WHERE id=?");
            $res = $stmt->execute([$title ,$futureDate, $id]); 
    
            if($res)
            {
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }
            else
            {           
            header("Location: ../updateForm.php?id=" . $id .  "mess=error");
            }
            $conn= null;
            exit();
        }     
        else 
        {
            header("Location: ../updateForm.php?id=" . $id . "mess=error");
        }       
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location: ../updateForm.php?id=" . $id .  "mess=error");
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are POSTing to the page but checking for GET.

Good manual pages to read:

- [Handling external variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Example:

```
$.post("app/update.php",
        {
            id: id
            alert(id);
        },
```

That will send a POST to the `app/update.php` script you have which contains the following:

```php
<?php
// $GET is not the same as $_GET
if(isset($GET['id'])){
    require '../includes/conn.php';
    include 'func.php';

    $id = $GET['id'];
    echo $id;
```

This will not work given that you are POSTing but looking incorrectly at $GET (which should be $_GET).

To fix change the following lines to:

```php
<?php
if($_POST['id']){
    require '../includes/conn.php';
    include 'func.php';

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo $id;
```

Please note that `$GET` and `$_GET` aren't the same things, nor are `$POST` and `$_POST`.

Comment: That alert can't be inside object construct

Comment: Fixed the GETS to $ _POST and moved the alert. The alerts now working just trying to get the update div to show onclick so I can test it

Comment: Please update your code in the question to show what you have changed